# pip returns errors in visual studio python tools

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip, windows-10

I am native Linux user and developer, but as I now use Windows 10 at work I have more than a little trouble doing what are normally the most basic tasks on my personal machine. I have created a python project from existing code but need to install the required modules for it. I try to do this as per MSDN instructions by accessing **Tools->Python Tools-> Python Environments**.

The process seems rather self explanatory however, when I try to upgrade pip I receive this error

`Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/`

I recieve the same error when trying to pip install NumPy

The module I really need at the moment though id from a github repository and not on PyPi. Normally I would just install it like so

`pip install https://github/u/r/l/file.zip`

but this returns a different error. The full output is in my pip error log just like this

```
C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py run on 04/12/18 15:00:30
Downloading/unpacking https://github.com/s4w3d0ff/python-poloniex/archive/v0.4.7.zip
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 493, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 291, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1090, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1086, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 924, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 159, in connect
    **self.conn_kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 491, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 327, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 543, in urlopen
    raise MaxRetryError(self, url, e)
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /s4w3d0ff/python-poloniex/archive/v0.4.7.zip (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1197, in prepare_files
    do_download,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1375, in unpack_url
    self.session,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 546, in unpack_http_url
    resp = session.get(target_url, stream=True)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 237, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 375, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='github.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /s4w3d0ff/python-poloniex/archive/v0.4.7.zip (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed)
```

Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Windows-10
occurs in both Visual studio 2015 and 2017
python 3.4 and 3.6
pip 1.5.6 and pip 9.0.1

Answer (score 0):

as the error mentions, maximum retry error, which means that there could be connection problem. make sure that your network admin, allows you to download the packages

Answer (score 0):

The initial exception says `getaddrinfo failed`, indicating that a DNS resolution failed.
I would run `nslookup github.com` and see if it resolves.